# How to include extended libraries like javascript to a cakephp view

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I am trying to include a library containing JavaScript and CSS into my CakePHP project, such that each folder in the library folder contains both CSS and .js files. How can I add a particular file into my CakePHP view using something like $this->Html->library('datatable.min.js')? Anything like that exist, will be very nice.

I know this works

`Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', ['block' => true]); ?>`

But isn't for a local resource in my project folder.

Comment: You can pass paths to local resources to the `script` and `css` functions.

Comment: For css, it will still prepend /css to it and for script it will only add resource in the script category, and append .js at the end.

Comment: If you pass a path starting with `/`, it should skip all of that, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, i just copied everything into the folder. At least it worked that way.